# Why does Event Horizon affect Vladimir while in Sanguine Pool?

Tags: league-of-legends

Why does Vlad get stunned of Event Horizon (Veigar E) while in Sanguine Pool?

And are there any other Area of Effect Crowd Control spells that can affect him during the duration of his Sanguine Pool?

> Sanguine Pool
> (Active): Vladimir sinks into a pool of blood becoming untargetable for 2
> seconds and slowing enemies above him by 40% for 1 second. Additionally,
> he deals magic damage every half second to them and heals himself for 12.5%
> of the damage done.
> Cost: 20% of current health
> Radius of AoE: 300

As far as I know, it's the only spell in game that can affect Vladimir during Sanguine Pool.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to a video of this happening? It might be due to the changes in the patch on June 17th, 2012  -  (patch notes link)  http://solariz.de/league-of-legends-changelog-history/lol-char-log?c=Veigar&v=1.0.0.141&atci=74

Comment: @RovingBlade It was so since vlad has come out (over a year ago?). Vlad never could puddle through Event Horizon.

Answer (score 1):

It affects him the exact same way any other non-targetable Crowd-Control effects would affect him, aside from Knockups and Displacements, like Malphites' Ult, Alistars' Q and W, Blitz's and Nauts' Pulls, etc.

Stuns and slows still affect him while he is in his pool, as stated in the [ability description](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper/Ability_Details) Mindquake provided. Similarly, On-Hit spells that apply a CC effect (Morganas' Dark Binding, Frozen Mallet, Phage, and Rylai's Procs, etc) will fail to apply them as he is untargetable. However, if a Proc or an on-hit effect lands before he goes into his Sanguine Pool, he will be affected by them still.

Comment: Can you give some examples of "non-targetable Crowd-Control effects"? Thanks

Comment: Singed's Slow Puddle, Blitz' Silence, Veigars' Ring, Galios' ult, and the above-mentioned knock-ups and displacements. Having never had the opportunity myself, I cannot say for certain whether Shens' taunt affects Sanguine Pool or not.

Comment: Now I'm curious - [What abitilies can still affect Vladimir while in Sanguine Pool?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78620/what-abitilies-can-still-affect-vladimir-while-in-sanguine-pool)

Comment: Something silly I saw yesterday in a ranked game: Malphite ulted on top of Vlad right as Vlad pooled, and was knocked into the air as the pool took effect. Floating pool of blood, floating pool of blood, you are so magical.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers/comments, Sanguine Pool also prevents certain things by allies from affecting Vlad. Some examples include Sona's heal Soraka's ultimate, and Will of the Ancient's aura effects.
Check out the notes under [Sanguine Pool](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper/Ability_Details)

Answer (score -1):

All spells that get cast *before* he enters the pool stay on Vlad (ignite, fiddle drain etc.), and Veigar's cage is considered one of these spells. It also affects flash and all other dashes. So does Jarvan's Ult.

Comment: While it is true that Damage Over Time spells applied to Vlad will remain active when he goes into Sanguine Pool, I don't think that this relates to Event Horizon from Veigar OR Cataclysm from Jarvan. The reason that Jarvan's Ult will follow a champion after they have flashes is because it targets an enemy champion, while Event Horizon just targets an area.

Comment: Master yi is able to run out of Jarvan ulti with he's ulti up, is this a bugg or?

Comment: Hey Isak, I am not sure about this. But since it's not related, maybe you can open a new question and figure out what is going on!

Comment: master yi running out is a bug, viegar and jarvan beeing able to stop vlad even in his pool is not a bug, its exactly like i said in my previous post: spells that apply dmg or status effects over time will remain if he pools after. If he is in pool alredy and the cage gets put directly onto his head, he can walk through (while in poolform)

Comment: Thanks for awnsers. But what's the reason for it?

Comment: Its simply something that riot wants/needs to do. Similar to Riots Anti-FUn "politic". 
They want Players Skill to be rewarded. If Veigar manages to place a "perfect" cage and lock 4 people in, and they all can simply dash out with a 3-4 sec cd spell, the veigar would feel pretty bad. Same with Fiddle Drain, Ignite etc. If you place it, you simply EXPECT it to do dmg, simply cause you wasted time and skill on using it. Same with Singeds W btw: If its placed and then Vlad trys to pool over it, he still gets slowed. If he pools and then the slow lands on top of him, he is not!