# What abitilies can still affect Vladimir while in Sanguine Pool?

Tags: league-of-legends

Vladimir's [Sanguine Pool](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper/Ability_Details#Sanguine_Pool) description is,

> Vladimir sinks into a pool of blood becoming *untargetable* for 2 seconds

There's detailed documentation for the abilities and effects that Vlad is unaffected by when in Sanguine Pool, such as

> - Vladimir is untargetable by allied abillities during the duration, such as [Soraka's  Wish](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Soraka_the_Starchild/Ability_Details#Wish) and [Sona's Aria of Perseverance](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sona_Maven_of_the_Strings/Ability_Details#Aria_of_Perseverance).
> - When Vladimir uses Sanguine Pool he is not affected by any auras, such as [Abyssal Scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Abyssal_Scepter)'s aura or [Soraka's Consecration](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Soraka_the_Starchild/Ability_Details#Consecration).
> - [Will of the Ancients](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_Ancients) will not affect Vladimir even if he is the holder of the item. This means Vladimir will not benefit from the spell vamp and bonus ability power of the aura while in Sanguine Pool.

However, there's [confusion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78026/why-does-event-horizon-affect-vladimir-while-in-sanguine-pool/78601#78601) [about](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2022123&page=2) [abilities](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1527450) [that](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=722397) still affect him. So what abilities still affect Vladimir while he is using Sanguine Pool?

Comment: Ideal answers will include videos or screenshots as evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Abilities that where cast BEFORE he pooled. Fiddles Drain is the example of an spell, and so is Swains Q and E; and example of an summonerspell is ignite. Aoe Abilites dont count into this (fiddle ult does no dmg, zyra ult does no dmg if pooled) but an aoe cage like veigars does count and stuns you.

So to shorten it up: everything that targets you directly and does dot will still do dmg in your pool, aoe abilities will not affect him, with the exception of Veigars Cage (which simply works this way, its something Riot wants cause it rewards skill)

Comment: What are some other exceptions that are like Event Horizon?

Comment: I cant think of anything else really. Jarvans ult obv keeps you in place, so do Anivia Wall or Trundle Pillar. I think Riot just threats Event Horizon like a chagne to the terrain, just like the abilities i named above, and people dont look at it that way.

Comment: What about [Swain's Nevermove](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Swain_the_Master_Tactician/Ability_Details#Nevermove)?

Comment: Doesn't count. But his E and his Q do dmg if you pool after getting  hit by it.

Comment: Can you double-check whether it works or not? According to [this thread](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1527450), Nevermore can snare Vlad in Sanguine Pool.

Comment: Nocturn's fear if cast before pool will still be able to fear you.

Comment: right, nocs fear is the same as fiddle drain. I am 100% sure nevermove cant hold you in place while you pool. It used to a year or so ago, but even then it was a bug. The only thing I dont know for sure righ tnow is zilean bombs. I played a lot of vlad, an di know bombs used to do dmg even if you pool if they are placed directly on you, but I am not sure anymore.

Comment: And how about [Galio's Idol of Durand](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Galio_the_Sentinel%27s_Sorrow/Ability_Details#Idol_of_Durand)? [This thread](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=722397) claims that it does.

Comment: No. Neither galios pool nor shens taunt (BUGGED RIGHT NOW!!) do affect vlad if he pools before they use it. If he pools at the exact samse momemt galio ult (and they both have 0 ping) he will get taunted in pool for 1 tick (0.5 sec) but thats highly unlikely (happened once in over 200 VLad games to me)

Comment: Does Karthus' barrier slow affect him?

Comment: It shouldn't but its not 100% bugfree. Cho Gaths Feral Scream and Cassios Ult CAN sometimes affect him after pooling, but they shouldn't. I think Riot stated that this has something to do with the skillshot bugs and they are working on fixing it (soonTM)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have already seen the [wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper/Ability_Details) on his abilities, where it mentions the abilities that still take effect.

Damage over time abilities or slows that are applied before pooling still take effect. Temporary environmental terrain such as Jarvan's Cataclysm still block him. Veigar's Event Horizon is considered an environmental terrain and will still stun Vladimir if he attempts to go through it while pooled.

Comment: The wiki seems incomplete, which is why I'm asking for clarification. For example, it doesn't explain why Event Horizon affects Vlad. Do you have a source that explains that Event Horizon is temporary environmental terrain?

Comment: Also, can you list the abilities that create temporary environmental terrains?